# How does Focus work with PanelSets in Roku?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I wanted to create a top nav-bar type structure in roku, so I extended Group, put my navBar component in, and added a panelSet to which I am adding and removing panels according to the navigation.

The problem I'm having is I can't figure out how to set focus on any of these panels.

I know that if I add a PanelSet directly to a Scene and then add a Panel to that PanelSet, Roku automatically gives that panel focus. A ListPanel is immediately scrollable, for instance. But how to do this when the PanelSet is inside a group or another component?

Comment: @swaran answer is right for best practices. But, one of another way to maintain a focus on panelSets to Follow old Roku documentation. which component is used in Panel Set?

Comment: hii. solved this issue? otherwise here https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/references/scenegraph/sliding-panels-nodes/overview.md Best example provided by Roku Community hopes this is very helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with setting the focus on PanelSet on whichever event you want to set it. For example try something like this--

```
m.panelset = createObject("roSGNode", "PanelSet")
m.panelset.setFocus(true)
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Any component Focus maintain Directly using setFocus(true). But, In a RowList, I tried to set focus. I use RowList in psnelset using your answer. But It's doesn't Work. Is there any solution or another way.

Comment: As far as I know, only Panel nodes can be added to PanelSet. I am not sure whether RowList can be added to PanelSet or not.

Comment: Ok, Thank you. I will tried. But Also Without PanelSet not maintain Focus in RowList. Here the image https://github.com/chaklasiyanikunj/KeyboardDialogExample/blob/master/NotMaintainEPGFocus.jpg

Comment: Read RowList docs carefully. May be you are missing something.